# How do I install python imaging library (PIL)?

Tags: python, software-installation, image-processing

How do I install the python imaging library (PIL) on Ubuntu?

I tried doing

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

but now when i run
    python selftest.py
(a script I got from somewhere on the http://pythonware.com/products/pil/ website)
I get (among other warning messages):

```
...
*** JPEG support not installed
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
...
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.
```

Have I somehow messed up the PIL -- how do I fix that?

Is maybe the PIL just fine, but that "selftest.py" is not really the right program for checking to see if PIL is installed properly -- how else can I tell if PIL is installed properly or not?

(I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS "Precise Pangolin").

(What I'm ultimately trying to do is to add a 2D barcode generator to some python code,
and all the 2D barcode generators I could find that were written in python all seemed to use the PIL).

Comment: You might want to try using the PIL in an application, there might just be a problem with **selftest.py**

Comment: In 18.04 it looks like you just do `sudo apt-get install python-pil` or `sudo apt-get install python3-pil`.

Comment: ^ Definitely, `sudo apt-get install python-pil` just worked for me on raspbian.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something similar happened to me, 
I solved this way

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
```

And try there installing via `pip install PIL`.

More on what `pip` is can be found [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html). In short is a convenient (and becoming a standard) way of installing python libraries.

if it continues to fail, it can be due to PIL searching those libraries in a different path.

> It turns out that the APT installations put the libraries under **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu** and PIL will search for them in **/usr/lib/**.
>   So you have to create symlinks for PIL to see them.

Try to see if libjpeg and libz libs exist in **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu** and make a symlink this way

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/lib/
```

---

**Source:** http://jj.isgeek.net/2011/09/install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-ubuntu-oneiric-64bits/

Comment: This did not work for me on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Comment: if it fits your needs, you could try 'pillow'. It is a drop in replacement for PIL.

Comment: Whenever possible, use `pillow`. It's essentially PIL but actually maintained.

Comment: Package zlib1g-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libjpeg
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg-dev
E: Unable to locate package libfreetype6-dev
E: Package 'zlib1g-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: The python-imaging package in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is linked to the JPEG library, and the changelog mentions multiarch breaking that prior to July 2011. Maybe this `selftest.py` had been broken because of that, too, but that didn't necessarily affect anything else.

Answer (score 31):

The above solution did not work for me on Ubuntu 12.10 as libjpeg was not available in the repository.

What did end up working for me was:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev
```

*If you get the error "You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list" then make sure that your /etc/apt/sources.list has deb-src entries which match your deb entries.*

Then you must symlink the files from their actual location on your server to the location where PIL expects them.

#### 32-bit version

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/libz.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/libjpeg.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/libfreetype.so
```

#### 64-bit version

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/libz.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/libjpeg.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/libfreetype.so
```

Finally, `pip install PIL`

#### Success!

[image]

---

### Update Sep 2014

Pillow is a more modern fork of PIL.

```
#jpeg support
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
#tiff support
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev
#freetype support
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
#openjpeg200support (needed to compile from source)
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/openjpeg.mirror/2.0.1/openjpeg-2.0.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf openjpeg-2.0.1.tar.gz
cd openjpeg-2.0.1/
sudo apt-get install cmake
cmake .
sudo make install
#install pillow
pip install pillow
```

Comment: Works for me on 13.04 with Pillow, without symlinking.

Comment: worked for me too (14.04 LTS 64-bit, unmodified from above):

sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev

Comment: I just needed "apt-get build-dep python-imaging"

Answer (score 14):

I just want to add, that  `pip install pil` no longer works, at least on my machine, you have to do

`pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL`

Comment: Try ``pip install Pillow`` instead of ``pip install pill`` (the latter does not exist)

Comment: @Lynob this is the same as PIL? and is suppoerted by TkInker?

Comment: @3kstc yes it is

Answer (score 4):

The above answers create links for x64 libraries in x86 locations. Instead I would download the [PIL source](http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz) then add these lines in setup.py:

```
    add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
    add_directory(library_dirs, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
```

after these lines (~line 211)

```
    # standard locations
    add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/local/lib")
    add_directory(include_dirs, "/usr/local/include")

    add_directory(library_dirs, "/usr/lib")
    add_directory(include_dirs, "/usr/include")
```

reinstall PIL. If you're using pip:

```
pip uninstall PIL
```

Then from the source directory run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apt-get install python-imaging` now [installs Pillow not PIL](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-imaging). As for `selftest.py`, you may need to [check out the source](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) to run it. And of course, you need to install the dependencies if you want PIL to support them e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev
```

To run a version of PIL newer than is included in Ubuntu::

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 as libjpeg was not available in the repository.

What did end up working for me

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to pip install Pillow in a virtualenv on 14.04 (not using system packages).

To build pillow from PyPI inside a virtualenv (Python 2.7):

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep pillow
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install pillow
```

... then you can import **PIL**.