# PIL install in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python, image-processing

Followed the steps [How do I install python imaging library (PIL)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil) for pre-setup libraries to install PIL on Ubuntu 14.04. However when I run `pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL` seeing the following errors:

```
building '_imagingft' extension

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imagingft.o

_imagingft.c:73:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory

 #include <freetype/fterrors.h>

                               ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-3ckD6N-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/PIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 57: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Was able to install `pip install Pillow` which is also image library I think so

Answer (score 15):

I have successfully installed PIL using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8 libjpeg62-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
sudo pip install Pillow
```

After these commands I could:

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.VERSION
'1.1.7'
```

Comment: You da real mvp! :D

Comment: i was able to `pip install Pillow` after just `sudo apt-get install build-dep python-imaging`.

Comment: @RyanTuck you added an extra `install` I think but this is much better than just installing a bunch of random packages that I don't know why I'm installing them.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, trying to install Pillow 2.0.0. I found solutions [here].(https://github.com/collective/buildout.python/issues/39)

In short, the location of the freetype library has moved in 14.04. An [expedient, if hacky fix](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python/issues/39#issuecomment-61180386), is to make a symlink. On my system, the library was in `/usr` not `/usr/local` so I did:

```
ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype
```

After doing this, I realized that I might have been able to solve it by updating Pillow to >=2.6.0.  But in any case, your issue is installing PIL, so the symlink fix is probably a good one for you.