# install pillow on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, python, django, pip

I'm crazy with Pillow. I already ask here, without solving:

[Python Django Mezzanine install fail for Pillow package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815508/python-django-mezzanine-install-fail-for-pillow-package)

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.

Installing pillow using pip or from github I have this error:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/decode.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/encode.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/map.o: File o directory non esistente
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/display.o: File o directory non esistente
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ctXrZt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Naturally I follow this also:

[PIL install in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507459/pil-install-in-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts/547553#547553)

Maybe there is some library conflict. I try to remove all and install again but I have always same error.

Have you a suggest?

Comment: You did use sudo to install pillow, right?

Comment: sure I use sudo also.

Comment: You forget to mention that you are using a virtualenv. Deactivate your virtualenv. Install pillow system wide with `sudo apt-get install python-pil`. Reactivate your virtualenv. Run `sudo pip install pillow`.

Comment: I already have installed most recent version of python-pil, anyway you have right I forgot to say that I'd insatll Pillow using virtualenv

Answer (score 18):

Firstly, you need the python-dev package because Pillow needs compile headers defined.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 you need few extra packages to get pillow working. Install all of them with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

This will work for both python 2.x and python 3.x. You might not need all of these, but at the very least you should install `libjpeg8-dev` and `zlib1g-dev` for JPEG and PNG support.

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04, use the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk
```

Detailed instructions can be found at official pillow documentation.

[Installation — Pillow (PIL Fork) 2.6.1 documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html)

Comment: For python 3 run `$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer a little.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: This is actually the most correct answer.  I don't understand quite why it got down-voted and then someone replaced it with a new answer -- should've just been modified with more explanations, no?

Comment: This worked for me on debian 8, but I had to remove libjpeg8-dev from the list.

Answer (score 0):

try to install this development dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
```

Comment: While this may  technically answer the question, it's usually better to include a bit of explanation as to what this will do, instead of just the raw commands.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above installs I still had the above error installing Pillow.

To fix the error, navigate to /usr/include:

```
cd /usr/include
```

Create a symlink, pointing to the freetype2-directory:

```
ln -s freetype2 freetype
```