# Error while creating a projrct with djangocms -p test1 test1 with exit status 1?

Tags: django

Please help me here. Stocked for 2 days. I tried all methods in internet but however not able to make a djangocms project.

Ubuntu version : Ubuntu 14 LTS

```
 (myPython2.7.9) sameer@sameer:~$ djangocms -p test1 test1

Database configuration (in URL format) [default sqlite://localhost/project.db]: 
django CMS version (choices: 2.4, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, stable, develop) [default stable]: 
Django version (choices: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, stable) [default stable]: 
Activate Django I18N / L10N setting (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Install and configure reversion support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Languages to enable. Option can be provided multiple times, or as a comma separated list. Only language codes supported by Django can be used here: en
Optional default time zone [default Asia/Kolkata]: 
Activate Django timezone support (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Activate CMS permission management (choices: yes, no) [default yes]: 
Use Twitter Bootstrap Theme (choices: yes, no) [default no]: 
Use custom template set [default no]: 
Load a starting page with examples after installation (english language only). Choose "no" if you use a custom template set. (choices: yes, no) [default no]: 
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
Command "/home/sameer/myPython2.7.9/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ybHpSc/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-oO5UEE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/sameer/myPython2.7.9/include/site/python2.7/Pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ybHpSc/Pillow/


**********************************************************

Check documentation at http://djangocms-installer.rtfd.org

**********************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sameer/myPython2.7.9/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/sameer/myPython2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 33, in execute
    verbose=config_data.verbose
  File "/home/sameer/myPython2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 93, in requirements
    output = subprocess.check_output(['pip'] + args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'pip', u'install', u'-q', u'django-cms<3.3', u'django-treebeard>=2.0', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-inherit/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-teaser/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75', u'djangocms-admin-style>=1.0.6', u'djangocms-text-ckeditor>=2.8.1', u'Django<1.9', u'pytz', u'django-reversion>=1.8.7,<1.9', u'django-classy-tags>=0.3.4.1', u'html5lib', u'Pillow>=2.3', u'django-sekizai>=0.7', u'six']' returned non-zero exit status 1
(myPython2.7.9) sameer@sameer:~$
```

As suggested :
I run the command

```
pip install -q django-cms<3.3 django-treebeard>=2.0 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-inherit/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-teaser/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 djangocms-admin-style>=1.0.6 djangocms-text-ckeditor>=2.8.1 Django<1.9 pytz django-reversion>=1.8.7,<1.9 django-classy-tags>=0.3.4.1 html5lib Pillow>=2.3 django-sekizai>=0.7 six

bash: 3.3: No such file or directory
```

Added sudo as gave permission error `sudo` :

```
sameer@sameer:~/Desktop$ sudo pip install -Ur /dev/stdin <<EOF
django-cms<3.3
django-treebeard>=2.0
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-inherit/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-teaser/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
djangocms-admin-style>=1.0.6
djangocms-text-ckeditor>=2.8.1
Django<1.9
pytz
django-reversion>=1.8.7,<1.9
django-classy-tags>=0.3.4.1
html5lib
Pillow>=2.3
django-sekizai>=0.7
six
EOF

[sudo] password for sameer: 
The directory '/home/sameer/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/sameer/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 3))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (164kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 77kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 4))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (234kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 65kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-inherit/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 5))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-inherit/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (171kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 37kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 6))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (197kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 204kB 19kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 7))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (147kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 17kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 8))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (159kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 36kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 9))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (198kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 204kB 45kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-teaser/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 10))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-teaser/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (159kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 56kB/s 
Collecting https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 11))
  Downloading https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75 (214kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 66kB/s 
Collecting django-cms<3.3 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 1))
Collecting django-treebeard>=2.0 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 2))
Collecting djangocms-admin-style>=1.0.6 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 12))
Collecting djangocms-text-ckeditor>=2.8.1 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 13))
Collecting Django<1.9 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 14))
  Downloading Django-1.8.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.2MB 40kB/s 
Collecting pytz (from -r /dev/stdin (line 15))
  Downloading pytz-2016.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (479kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 481kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting django-reversion<1.9,>=1.8.7 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 16))
Collecting django-classy-tags>=0.3.4.1 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 17))
  Downloading django_classy_tags-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html5lib (from -r /dev/stdin (line 18))
Collecting Pillow>=2.3 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 19))
  Downloading Pillow-3.2.0.tar.gz (10.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.3MB 61kB/s 
Collecting django-sekizai>=0.7 (from -r /dev/stdin (line 20))
  Downloading django_sekizai-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from -r /dev/stdin (line 21))
Collecting django-select2<5.0,>=4.3 (from djangocms-link==1.7.2->-r /dev/stdin (line 6))
Collecting django-formtools>=1.0 (from django-cms<3.3->-r /dev/stdin (line 1))
  Downloading django_formtools-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 35kB/s 
Installing collected packages: Django, django-formtools, djangocms-admin-style, django-classy-tags, django-sekizai, html5lib, django-treebeard, django-cms, Pillow, djangocms-text-ckeditor, pytz, django-reversion, djangocms-column, djangocms-googlemap, djangocms-inherit, django-select2, djangocms-link, djangocms-style, djangocms-file, djangocms-picture, djangocms-teaser, djangocms-video
  Found existing installation: html5lib 0.999
    Uninstalling html5lib-0.999:
      Successfully uninstalled html5lib-0.999
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lv0hdex4/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8lal3cl9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-lv0hdex4/Pillow/setup.py", line 767, in <module>
        zip_safe=not debug_build(), )
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 583, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-lv0hdex4/Pillow/setup.py", line 512, in build_extensions
        ' using --disable-%s, aborting' % (f, f))
    ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lv0hdex4/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8lal3cl9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lv0hdex4/Pillow/
```

error code 1 ..

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

Then the above command worked flawless

However :

```
Please wait while I install dependencies
/home/sameer/.virtualenvs/modern_business/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/sameer/.virtualenvs/modern_business/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/home/sameer/.virtualenvs/modern_business/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Please help in this :)

Comment: Your error indicates that `pip` is getting stuck on something. What version of Ubuntu are you running? What happens when you run [this command](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15596270/) in a terminal?

Comment: Dear @NathanOsman . The command you suggested giving no such file or directory error. Please suggest

Comment: Please have a look to the output . Still some error. Thank you @NathanOsman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the command together and run it manually, without the `-q` quite argument so you can see where it's breaking:

```
pip install -Ur /dev/stdin <<EOF
django-cms<3.3
django-treebeard>=2.0
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-inherit/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-file/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-picture/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-teaser/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-video/archive/master.zip?1459675664.75
djangocms-admin-style>=1.0.6
djangocms-text-ckeditor>=2.8.1
Django<1.9
pytz
django-reversion>=1.8.7,<1.9
django-classy-tags>=0.3.4.1
html5lib
Pillow>=2.3
django-sekizai>=0.7
six
EOF
```

In my case, in a brand new Python3 virtualenv, I had a load of missing `wheel` errors. I installed wheel with `pip install wheel` then the whole list installed fine. You may well have different issues because there are a lot of different build dependencies for this stuff.

Tested successfully (here) with:

```
python3 -mvenv testvenv
. testvenv/bin/activate
pip install wheel
```

---

Update. Looking at your output a few things of note:

1. **Use a virtualenv!** This doesn't directly fix your issue but don't install this junk in the system copy of Python. You'll overwrite things the system needs and one day that will break things.

   A virtualenv (as illustrated above) gives you a nice non-root environment you can install whatever you like into. It takes some getting use to (you have to activate them each time you want to do stuff in *that* environment) but they're well worth it.

   See http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
2. You don't have the build dependencies installed for Pillow. It needs various C libraries for image encoding.

   See https://askubuntu.com/a/687637/449

Comment: Thanks @Oli . However please tell me how to use the command without -q. I am a beginner so please suggest.

Comment: I have added the output in main question. Please have a look once.

Comment: Thanks a ton...:) Please tell a way to get rid of the SNIMissingWarning and nsecurePlatformWarning.

Comment: It is just a warning —not an error— but it seems like it could be a side effect of having run these commands as root (you have cached files owned by root that your user cannot replace/remove/etc). Another reason to not do this stuff at system level.