# sudo apt-get install python-pil on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, apt, python

I'm restricted to `sudo apt-get install` and I need to install python-pil so the command should be `sudo apt-get install python-pil`,but here is the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pil
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-pil is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-pil' has no installation candidate
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: And Ubuntu 12.04 is about to reach the end of its support. Consider upgrading while it's still time.

Comment: @CelticWarrior my question is restricted to `apt-get install` method of installation, not `pip`.

Comment: That's why I told you to read both the answers and comments.

Comment: @CelticWarrior this one?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil#comment456063_156520

Comment: That's the one indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems PIL is not supported, I have installed Pillow instead.

> Pillow is the friendly PIL fork by Alex Clark and Contributors. PIL is
>   the Python Imaging Library by Fredrik Lundh and Contributors.

So command should be:

`sudo apt-get install python-pillow`