# E: Package 'python-imaging' has no installation candidate Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, python, virtualization

I am trying to Install and configure libvirtd by following this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-libvirt libvirt-bin libvirt0 python-imaging python-numpy virtinst virt-viewer virt-manager
```

After I run that, I get the error:

```
Package python-imaging is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python-pil:i386 python-pil

E: Package 'python-imaging' has no installation candidate
```

I try to install python imaging library, by following the comment that is giving in this post:

[How do I install python imaging library (PIL)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil)

such as:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

after I run this command I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

Someone in his comment say:

> If you get the error "You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list" then make sure that your /etc/apt/sources.list has deb-src entries which match your deb entries.
>   Then you must symlink the files from their actual location on your server to the location where PIL expects them.

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: A quick scan (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python-imaging) shows the packages is available up to xenial (16.04) but not later.  I won't provide more advice as I don't know enough to foresee any consequences (I don't know python) of adding that xenial package to a bionic system, but maybe a PPA contains your solution - someone else with more knowledge may be able to help you.  (*this is intended as learning info & possible crumbs*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this error message statement:

```
However the following packages replace it: python-pil:i386 python-pil
```

It seems all you need to do is install `python-pil` now:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pil python3-pil
```

The whole command will be:

```
sudo apt install python-libvirt libvirt-bin libvirt0 python-numpy virtinst virt-viewer virt-manager python-pil
```